# Is SO the correct place to ask a theoretical question such as: "If I hire a graphic designer to make an animated image, how would I add it to my app?"

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

I'm thinking of hiring a graphic designer to make an animation for my game that I am developing, but I am confused on how apps actually incorporate these animations (e.g. do graphic designers just supply me with a video or gif that I embed, or do I get each individual image component and I am responsible for animating it?).

However, I am not sure Stack Overflow is the correct place to ask this type of "theoretical" question. Can anybody let me know if SO is not the appropriate place to ask a question similar to:

> If I hire a graphic designer to make an animated image, how would I add it to my app?

Comment: The _"If I hire a graphic designer..."_ part is irrelevant. Other than that, the question is probably on topic **IF** you make it specific to the (language, tools, etc.) that you're using and explain what kind of animation it is. Moreover, you should make your own research beforehand. It's quite likely that that type of question has been asked before.

Comment: The trouble with this is that it's very broad. It depends on the App and the animation. I imagine that a designer will supply you with what you ask for. There's no "one size fits all" that would allow for this to be answerable.

Comment: I wonder whether a question like "What would I need to be prepared to provide to a graphic designer I hire to create animations for my app?" - would be appropriate on [graphicdesign.se] - questions about hiring certainly are. Here's their on topic page. https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Thank you all. Yes I believe my question is too broad for SO as it is stated. I am looking for more of a conceptual response, so it would probably be best for the graphic design stack exchange.

Comment: There's also the [Game Development SE](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) but you should check out their help center, Meta, and try to find a similar question before asking.

Answer (score 3):

This assumes that *you* know how to add graphics that *you* did into your application.  If *you* don't know how to do that, then asking Stack Overflow or any other network site to teach you that would not be on-topic or a reasonable use of volunteer's time.

If there's some more complex facet of adding the graphics that is nuanced but not exposed here for some reason, then *perhaps* that could be suitable for the network.